# Downloaded file corrupted

Tags: java, download, glassfish-3

My application contains 100MB of an AVI file, which is linked to an anchor tag, by clicking the link a user can download the file.

The problem is when you download the file, it comes corrupted. What am I missing?

(Application is Java / JSF and the hosting Server is Glassfish V3)

Comment: Who's streaming the file to the response? You by hand-written code? Or the server by its own code (because the file is just in public webcontent)? If it's yourself, then the code may be bogus. If it's the server, then the file itself may be simply corrupt.

Comment: In continuation to BalusC's comment, you may want to consider running an md5 test on both the original file and the downloaded file, to check if they're the same. If they are the same, maybe the problem is with the client player. Did you try playing the file with other players?

Comment: I did not write any particular code to stream the file, the main portion of the markup is an anchor tag: <a href="myfilename.avi">click to download</a>. I am really have no idea whether I have to write some additional codes, please advice me.

Comment: The original file plays on Windows media player but not the downloaded one. The original file shows the correct properties (frame size, frame rate ect) when right click and choose properties, but not the downloaded one.

Comment: Do you have any `Filter` which is mapped on `/*` and which is changing the response somehow? Did you test other types (DOC, XLS, JPG, PDF, MP4, etc) and sizes (1KB, 1MB, 10MB, etc) of files as well?

Comment: If the downloaded file's tiny, try opening it with a text editor.  It may be an HTML error page.

Comment: I do not have any filters. The problem with large file size only.